# GIT branching -- local repo branch

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

Let's say I have a project, and a main branch, master.  Master contains a web solution, and I want to create a new branch, to turn master's solution's css into sass.

I create a new branch called scss.

I work off the branch on scss.  Meanwhile, I need to also work on the master branch.  So I switch between the two.

When I switch from scss to master, Visual Studio asks if I want to update the file that has been changed, I clicked "yes to all".  And I expect the scss files to disappear from the solution explorer, but they're still there.  I was wondering if someone can explain to me what's going on locally when I switch branch in the same directory, are the files supposed to actually change?  Should I have started a different directory with the new branch?  What is the right workflow and what should I expect here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always move between branches  **till there is no conflict in the  modified files** .

This featuer is actually required sometimes. If two branches are having almost same changes, and by mistake/unknowingly you are developing in branch1 but the commit is supposed to go to branch2. So you can easily checkout the branch and the modified files will be still in *modified state in branch2 branch also, and you can commit here.

If you like to keep the modified changes in branch1 only. either

- Commit ( prefer this option, add meaningful commit, saying till what progress you made int that branch.)
- Stash

Also if there is any conflict while switching branch, git will throw an error saying

> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten
>   by checkout: [list of files changed in the active branch] Please,
>   commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
>   Aborting

If that changes belongs to the same branch, either commit or stash.
If not for the other branch, do git stash and switch to the other branch and apply the stash over there.

Answer (score 1):

While you are developing and your files' changes are not commited on current branch (local or master), the changes you made are not linked to any branch (the commit ID contains the reference of the actual link) so what you are experiencing is the expected behavior. I make use of that when I start working on a task and I realize I am on a different branch so I just switch to the correct branch.

You have 2 solutions from what I see:
1. You stash your changes before switching branch
2. You commit the changes before switching branch

The stash will be hidden until you apply it back to the correct branch and the commit means the changes were added to a branch.

Comment: I guess I should had been more specific.  I actually already committed before I switch, but I still see the files from branch scss when I switch to master.  Is that normal?

Comment: No, that is not normal. But my guess is that this comes from Visual Studio options or that popup you're seeing "Update changes". Try hitting "No" option when you get that again. I am using GIT from iTerm so I do not have this issues.